# How to use classes from other module in JSDoc annotations

Tags: class, annotations, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, checkjs

Best explained with an example:

**some-class.js**

```
function SomeClass() { /* ... */ }

SomeClass.prototype.doSomething = function() { /* ... */ };

export function createSomeClass() {
    return new SomeClass();
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { createSomeClass } from './some-class';

/**
 * @param {SomeClass} someClass 
 */
function foo(someClass) {
    someClass.doSomething();
}

var someClass = createSomeClass();
someClass.doSomething();
```

This code leads to errors in VSCodes TypeScript checker and won't provide code completion for the class inside `foo`:

[image]

An alternative would be to export the class constructor and import it in `index.js` which gives me full code completion but adds a warning due to the unused import of the class:

[image]

What I also don't like about this solution is that it "leaks" the class to the outside which is not necessary otherwise due to the `createSomeClass` factory.

Is there some way to have full annotations & code completion without the unused import of the class?